# New laptop has terrible WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My new laptop has terrible WiFi. While my laptop from 2006(!) are able to find over 20 networks in the apartment-complex that I live in, this one is barely able to find mine, and often disconnects. The computer is an ASUS F511CA, and I have confirmed that all drivers are up to date, as well as I have disabled the power-saving option that allows the system to turn off the network. Is it still possible to hope that this is software-related, or should I simply send it in for reparation?

Comment: Try an older version of the driver. Newer does not always mean better.

Comment: You should probably try to replace it. If it's new, it shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Please provide the specific network adapter you have.  Also provide the specific which 802.11 mode your using.  Also specify which frequency 2.4Ghz or 5.0 ghz your using.

Comment: I am using Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG. I do not know where I am to find which 802.11 mode I am using. I am using 2.4Ghz, B+G+N.

Comment: Are you holding it wrong?

Comment: Older version did not work. What do you mean, lornix?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Iornix was referring to Apple's Antennagate debacle where Steve Jobs said users were holding their new iphones wrong, which attenuated the signal and caused bad cellular performance.  Its humour.